# How to use this command with PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, replace

I need to run the following command against a library of about 3000 documents, but have been stymied getting a working regex (not my strongest suit), or the equivalent of the `/v` option in PowerShell. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

My command

```
C:\findstr /v "<?xml version=" filename.htm > ..\testOut\filename.htm
```

Where I am so far with PowerShell

```
(Get-Content ($srcfiles)) | Foreach-Object {$_.srcfiles -replace '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>', ("")} | Set-Content  ($srcfiles)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Get-Content` returns an array of lines, not the full text of the file as a single string.

If all you are doing is trying to remove the xml declaration from each file, try this, assuming `$srcfiles` is a collection of full file paths:

```
foreach($file in $srcfiles)
{
    $content = Get-Content $file | ? { $_ -notmatch "<\?xml[^>]+>" }
    $content | Set-Content $file -Force
}
```

Basically, loop through all the files, get the content of each file, ignore any xml declaration line, then push that data back to the original file. I am doing this in two steps because PowerShell won't let you write content to a file in the same pipeline you are getting the data in.

Answer (score 0):

```
$path = "C:\Path\To\Documents"
$outputPath = "C:\Path\To\OutputDocuments"

Get-ChildItem $path | % { 
   $content = ( Get-Content -Raw $_ ) -replace '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>', '' 
   $fileName = Join-Path $outputPath $_.Name
   Set-Content -Path $fileName -Value $content
}
```

If you're on PowerShell 2.0 or lower, replace "Get-Content -Raw" with "Get-Content -ReadCount 0".

You'll also need to filter the output of Get-ChildItem to only return files, rather than directories. In PowerShell 3.0 or higher, you can add the "-File" parameter to Get-ChildItem. Otherwise, try this:

```
Get-ChildItem $path | ? { $_.GetType() -eq "FileInfo" } | % {
```